# Natural logarithm calculation in RGR example

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm studying the book *Statistical Methods for Research Workers* by R.A. Fisher (1934). I'm in chapter 2, called diagrams. It contains an example of Relative Growth Rate of babies’ weight growth in their first 13 weeks of life. I understand how RGR is calculated, but trying to replicate the table one, I could not get how to obtain the natural log of weight column numbers. Someone knows how the calculation of those numbers was made?

For example, if you get, Ln(110) you get 4.70, and not 0.0953  as the book show. But if you do the Logarith part as usual, them the increase column calculation fit the table. Can a natural log have two equivalent decimal representations?

[image: Table 1, page 28, statistics methods for research worker - R. A. Fisher.]

Comment: $\ln 1\color{red}.10\approx 0.0953$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the weight was converted to units of $100$ ounces

before the natural logarithm was taken.

Thus, the numbers in the column labeled Natural Log. of Weight are obtained

by dividing the Weight in Ounces by $100$ and then taking the natural logarithm,

or by taking logarithm of the Weight in Ounces and then subtracting the natural logarithm of $100$.

Comment: Do you know why it does not matter for the RGR to transform the weigths in that way?

Comment: As I said, it's just an offset by $\ln 100$, and that does not affect the difference between successive entries in that column, since all the entries are offset by the same amount